# T-SQL Columns to rows with dynamic data not the same amount of rows

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot, sql-server-2014

I've done this using Python but was wondering if the same was possible using T-SQL. So here is the result from my SQL currently.

```
locality | group | amount
-------------------------
A        | X     | 1
A        | Y     | 2
A        | Z     | 3
B        | X     | 4
B        | Y     | 5
C        | X     | 6
C        | Z     | 7
D        | X     | 8
```

What I want is to pivot the table so it looks like this

```
locality | X | Y | Z 
---------------------
A        | 1 | 2 | 3
B        | 4 | 5 | 0
C        | 6 | 0 | 7
D        | 8 | 0 | 0
```

As you can see, each locality may or may not have all groups. I've used A-D and X-Z but these can be in their dozens so this is just a cut down example.

I'm out of my depth in T-SQL unfortunately and was wondering how I'd go about getting this working in T-SQL and depend less on Python.

I've not tried anything as yet as not sure where to even start I'm afraid.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can try to dynamic pivot.

use condition aggregate function with dynamic SQL to make it.

The key point might be how to contact SQL string for condition aggregate function.

We can try to use `STUFF` function to dynamic creates a condition aggregate function as  `@cols` variable.

```
MAX(CASE WHEN [group] = 'X' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as 'X', 
MAX(CASE WHEN [group] = 'Y' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as 'Y', 
MAX(CASE WHEN [group] = 'Z' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as 'Z'
```

so that the code might look as below.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);    

SET @cols = STUFF((
            SELECT distinct ', MAX(CASE WHEN [group] = '''+ [group] + ''' THEN amount ELSE 0 END)' + ' as '''+[group]+''''
            FROM T
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1,1,'')

SET @query = 'SELECT locality, ' + @cols + '  
FROM T t1
GROUP BY locality  '
EXEC(@query)
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=9680472d2ee1e2fd76901596dc522a00)

Comment: Missing `QUOTENAME` (and then you don't need extra quotes)